why replicas contain a leader when describing a topic?
I'm new to Kafka, sorry if my question sounds dumb. Let's say we create a topic with 3 partitions and 3 replications as : /kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic helloworld --partitions 3 --replication-factor 3, and the description of the topic is as below:
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 0 | Leader: 0 | Replicas: 0,1,2 | Isr: 0,1,2
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 1 | Leader: 1 | Replicas: 1,2,0 | Isr: 1,2,0
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 2 | Leader: 2 | Replicas: 2,0,1 | Isr: 2,0,1

I don't understand why the Replicas column contain the leader broker, for example, the second line for Partition 1, the leader's broker id is 0, and the replicas column even includes this leader's broker id 0.
As my understanding is, a leader is different to a replica, consumers only read/write from/to leader, a replica is just a backup in case the leader fails, that's why the term "replica" come from, so why the "Replicas" columns include leader? shouldn't the output be something like:
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 0 | Leader: 0 | Replicas: 1,2 | Isr: 0,1,2
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 1 | Leader: 1 | Replicas: 2,0 | Isr: 1,2,0
Topic: helloworld | Partition: 2 | Leader: 2 | Replicas: 0,1 | Isr: 2,0,1

